# Basic conversation question

Tags: word-choice, translation, meaning

Good morning.

I was wondering if I can get some help with translating a sentence from Japanese to English, and also if I can receive some feedback about the way that I try to speak Japanese.

**Me:** アメリカ人の中このチャネルはSF5をゲームしてくださいといっていました。

**What I thought I was saying:** The American people in the channel said "Please play SF5 (Street Fighter 5)."

**What I wanted to say:** The American people in the chatroom are saying to please play street fighter 5!

**A response I got:** アメリカ人もSF5やるきか。

**What I think it maybe means:** I see も so I think this is kind of like "too" in English. So I think the person is saying I want you to play SF5 too? やる　- I wasn't aware of using this instead of げーむをする. Also, I don't know what きか at the end means.

**I apologize for any confusion. I took 3 semesters of Japanese but my last semester was around 2010. So it has been a long time. I just thought I would try and see if I can try and hold basic internet conversations.

Comment: Did you pick up the difference between 時 and 人?

Comment: I am not sure what 時 means, is it another way to say like a kind of nationality?

Comment: As naruto's answer says, 時 means something completely different from 人. When you ask a question, it's better only to type what you understand, so people are able to answer your question in a way that you can understand. Converting kana to kanji automatically without knowing the kanji is a recipe for disaster, because you can't rely on the converter to understand what you mean...

Comment: Woops yeah I actually put 人　when I was typing to the people earlier and not 時 . 時 is a mistake just for this post I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> アメリカ時の中このチャネルはSF5をゲームしてくださいといっていました。

Unfortunately, this sentence is broken, and it must have been difficult for them to figure out what you wanted to say. If I had to translate this sentence back into English, it would be something like "In American time this channel was saying please game SF5".

The biggest mistake is 時【じ】, which means *time*. I guess you wanted to say アメリカ人【じん】 (American *people*). The correct sentence would be "このチャンネルのアメリカ人はSF5をプレイしてくださいと言っています。" (if you actually wanted to use present tense)

> アメリカ人もSF5やるきか。

- ゲーム(を)する and ゲーム(を)やる are the same, except that the latter sounds more casual and colloquial.
- きか in this context is 気【き】+か, where 気 means 'intention/will' and か is the question marker (the particle which turns the sentence into a question). ～する気だ means "to have an intention to do ～".

So the sentence means "(This) American is gonna play SF5 too?", and I think this was said not to you but to someone else in the chatroom. People usually don't address *you* (the second person) as アメリカ人, unless your screen name was `アメリカ人`.

Comment: Yeah my bad, 時　was a typo for my post here, I actually did put 人 when I was typing to the people.

Comment: Oh in that case, I think they could at least guess your intention right :-)